# Scroll bar behaving strangely when height set

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a chat widget, which looks something like this:

[image: UI]

What I am trying to do, is specify a maximum height for the entire chat, and then have everything fill in, without needing to specify any fixed heights within the chat itself. My code is below:

#### HTML

```
<section class="boxlr-chat">
    <div class="boxlr-chat-header">
        {{ Title }}
        <span>{{ Subtitle }}</span>
    </div>
    <ul class="boxlr-chat-messages">
        <li>{{ Message }}</li>
        <li>{{ Message }}</li>
        <li>{{ Message }}</li>
        <li>{{ Message }}</li>
        <li>{{ Message }}</li>
        <li>{{ Message }}</li>
        <li>{{ Message }}</li>
        <li>{{ Message }}</li>
        <li>{{ Message }}</li>
        <li>{{ Message }}</li>
        <li>{{ Message }}</li>
    </ul>
    <form action="#" class="boxlr-chat-form">
        <input type="text" />
        <button type="submit">Send</button>
    </form>
</section>
```

#### CSS

```
.boxlr-chat {
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 200px;

    background-color: #1abc9c;
}

.boxlr-chat-header {
    background-color: #2ecc71;
}

.boxlr-chat-messages {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    height: 150px;
    overflow: scroll;

    background-color: #3498db;
}

.boxlr-chat-form {
    width: 100%;

    background-color: #34495e;
}
```

What I want, is for the message `<ul>` to fill the box except for the header and form, even if there are not a large number of messages. When it fills up, I want just the chat to scroll, while keeping the title and form 'attached' to the top and bottom so they are always visible. I have 'sort-of' been able to do it, however I had to specify `height: 150px` on `boxlr-chat-messages` which I don't want to do. Also, when scrolling it gets to a point at the bottom where you can't scroll any more, but the scroll bar is only at 80%.

[image: Scroll]

What is the best way to fix

1. The scroll bar
2. The chat layout

Sorry about the poor title, I couldn't find a better thing to call it. I have a JSFiddle which is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/BenedictLewis/5qnfB/2/) if that is helpful.

Comment: I haven't noticed an issue with the scrollbar in the Fiddle. It might be your browser. Also, why not simply put the max-height on .boxlr-chat-messages? If it's not that simple, I apologize, but I might not have understood the issue.

Comment: What browser are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You can fix the weird scroll behaviour by changing `overflow: scroll;` to `overflow: auto;`.

As for the height of the chat window... why not just set the height of the `.boxlr-chat-messages` to whatever height you want? Since it has a fixed height and `overflow: auto;`, it won't affect the header and footer.